# xslt, how to select tags, based on the contents of another same level tag

Tags: xslt

My source file looks like this:

```
<stuff> 
<s>
    <contents>
      <code>503886</code>
      <code>602806</code>
    </contents>
    ...
</s>
<p>
    <code>344196</code>
    <export>true</export>
    ...
</p>
<!-- more 's' and 'p' tags -->
...
</stuff>
```

I need to iterate over 's' and choose those - which inside 'contents' tag have a 'code' that belongs to a 'p' that has export=true.

I've been trying to solve this for the last couple of hours.
Please share some ideas.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a one-liner XPath solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kSByCode" match="s" use="contents/code"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="p[export='true']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('kSByCode',code)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<stuff>
    <s>
        <contents>
            <code>503886</code>
            <code>602806</code>
        </contents>
    </s>
    <p>
        <code>602806</code>
        <export>true</export>
    </p>
</stuff>
```

Output:

```
<s>
    <contents>
        <code>503886</code>
        <code>602806</code>
    </contents>
</s>
```

**Note**: Whenever there are cross references, use keys.

**Edit**: Missed iterate over `s` part. Thanks, Dimitre!

**Edit 2**: Re reading this answer I saw that it might be confusing. So, for a expression **selecting** the nodes, use:

```
key('kSByCode',/stuff/p[export='true']/code)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to iterate over 's' and choose
>   those - which inside 'contents' tag
>   have a 'code' that belongs to a 'p'
>   that has export=true.

**Use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=
 "/*/s
      [code
      =
       /*/p
          [export='true']
                      /code]"/>
```

Comment: +1 I've missed *iterate over `s`* part. I've edited my answer.